# Problems baking my blog using JBake 2.5.1

Tags: jbake

When I am trying to "bake" my JBake project using `jbake -b` I keep getting the following error.

```
➜  git:(master) ✗ jbake -b
JBake v2.5.1 (2017-01-31 23:24:52PM) [http://jbake.org]

18:28:33.646 WARN  c.o.o.c.d.r.ODatabaseRecordAbstract$2 - Current implementation of storage does not support sbtree collections
An unexpected error occurred: Cannot create database
```

Is there a way to tell JBake to be a bit more verbose? Is anyone familiar with that kind of error?

I installed JBake using sdkman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your using Java 9, if so then you're experiencing this [issue](https://github.com/jbake-org/jbake/issues/408) which is due to the version of OrientDB bundled with JBake 2.5.1, should be fixed with JBake 2.6.0 which bundles a later version and is due out soon.